# Different Error colors/settings in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is there any way I can display ESLint/Prettier errors differently from TypeScript errors in WebStorm? Like orange squiggles for Prettier errors and red for TS?

Comment: As far as I know each "external linter" should have a corresponding Inspection entry (internal mechanics used for reporting the errors/warming back to the IDE). Since it's an inspection, it uses Severity to denote how important it is (and how it is displayed). The IDE also allows you to create your own Severities.

Comment: So the idea is: if the Severity is NOT hardcoded internally (some linter tools for PHP have them this way), you should then be able to define you own Severity, apply desired style and use it for that inspection. Have a look and try it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-inspection-severities.html ALSO https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/eslint.html#ws_eslint_configure_highlighting